# smack - invite users to muc room as moderators

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have this code, but `muc.grantModerator(user.getJid())` is failing because the user is not inside the room yet.

Any suggestions to invite users to muc room as moderators?

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomjid);


for (User user : invitedUsers) {
    muc.invite(user.getJid(), "");
    muc.grantModerator(user.getJid());
}
```

Comment: Moderator it's a "temporary" status for connected users. You can try to to invite given users and grant him "admin" role. Than, on receiver client, you can check after each join if you are an admin and so grant yourself moderator status. If you like this way I can answer with a snippet.

Comment: My goal is everyone in the room can check who is subscribed to messages in the room. https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/#subscribing-to-muc-sub-events If as admin a user can check the subscription list then it's ok to me!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the pseudo-subscribe provided by ejabber.It looks like as an automatic bookmark subscription + automatic listeners declared one by one in SMACK (MessageListener, DefaultParticipantStatusListener, SubjectUpdatedListener and so on...). To get output you need I think you'll have to implement something custom, I'm not able to find any official XEP about that, it's probably a custom feature of Ejabber that allow with 1 IQ to resume up to 6 "atomic" IQ

Comment: it's a late answer but I was facing same question. The answer is you need to create a members-only room and grantsMembership to the users before send them the invitation. Later you can use room.getOwners() and room.getMembers() to get the list you want